# Highchart Stock exportChartLocal to PDF is not working with a hugedata and boostThreshold enabled

Tags: javascript, pdf, highcharts

Using **Highchart** **Stock** with **Boost** module to plot a line chart with a data greater than 50,000 with `boostThreshold` 10,000. Exporting locally to PNG, JPEG and SVG is working properly. But when tried to export locally to **PDF** it is not working and gives error.
*The error is found only when exporting locally for a data greater than the*`boostThreshold`.

The code used to export to pdf locally is -

```
chart.exportChartLocal(
  {
    type: 'application/pdf',
    filename: 'my-pdf',
  },
);
```

It gives the following error in the console.

```
exporting.js?0319:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plotOptions' of undefined
    at c.Chart.getSVG (exporting.js?0319:18)
    at HTMLBodyElement.eval (index.js?7c41:199)
```

If anybody has a solution for this issue, sharing it here would be a great help.

Comment: Hi @singularity, I have tried to reproduce the issue, but everything seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gumj6zk5/ Could you adapt the example to show the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. Tried the example in the fiddle, with a few of our settings too. Looks its working here. But in our application it is still failing. It may be due to some lack of memory also as our application itself is huge and handles a lot of data. I will be keep trying. Will update here if i could solve it.
Also would like to add here that i could find this in the console. [www.highcharts.com/errors/28/](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/28/)

Comment: It looks that the chart has some problem with offline exporting. Do you use `exporting.allowHTML` feature?

Comment: @ppotaczek No we are not using it and same error with `exporting.allowHTML` `true` or `false`

Comment: Does the basic exporting work correctly? In general, offline-exporting does not support all browsers and features.